# Gradle call programatically ./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionStageDebug

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

How can I execute `./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionStageDebug` from my custom task? I tried this code but it does not work:

```
task myTask {
doFirst {
    tasks.assembleStageDebug().execute()
    tasks.crashlyticsUploadDistributionStageDebug().execute()
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never execute tasks directly. Instead define dependencies between them:

```
task myTask
myTask.dependsOn assembleStageDebug, crashlyticsUploadDistributionStageDebug
```